# Using kineticjs is a way of trigger events like jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using kineticjs for a script of resizing images I saw on [that](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) page.
My problem is, every time you hover an image, the anchors for resizing are redrawn.

Since I'm using `groups` for the images, after an image is resized I have to reposition `group` `X` and `Y` so when the anchors are redrawn they wont be on the wrong place(the last `x` and `y` position of the `group`).

There is probably more than 1 way of doing this, but I think would be easier if I just call `dragmove` event on that group.

So is there a way of calling events on kineticjs like this jquery?

```
$('#id').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the simulate() method which belongs to Kinetic.Node and so is available for all Shapes etc...

```
group.simulate('dragmove')
```

Comment: It looks like the API was updated at some point to use `fire` instead. See [latest docs](http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Group.html#toc32).